# stardog sesame remote access - class org.openrdf.repository.base.AbstractRepository not found?

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-access, sesame, stardog

I am trying to integrate my application with stardog. The application accesses already other RDF repositories in Java via sesame remoteRepository interface.

Stardog writes in http://docs.stardog.com/#_using_sesame that this can be achieved via a use of StardogRepository() - but without saying what libs to include.

After a little search inside the stardog 4.1.3 installation I found and included in eclipse's WEB-INF/lib:

```
stardog-api-4.1.3.jar
stardog-sesame-core-4.1.3.jar
```

After that, the eclipse Java compiler shows no errors in the code but one error in the project path, saying:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for
>   org.openrdf.repository.base.AbstractRepository. Fix the build path
>   then try building this project

After project cleaning this problem remains.

This class org.openrdf.repository.base.AbstractRepository is defined in the lib eclipse-rdf4j-2.0.1.jar, which is also present in the WEB-INF/lib folder (with or without this latter eclipse-rdf4j-2.0.1.jar the problem is unchanged).

What lib shell I include in order to have these 2 lines of code in http://docs.stardog.com/# compiled?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint.

Comment: Meanwhile I discovered that the class org.openrdf.repository.base.AbstractRepository should be inside stardog-sesame-core-4.1.3.jar as seems from http://docs.stardog.com/java/snarl/com/complexible/stardog/sesame/StardogRepository.html - but is not. From the class StardogRepositoryConnection a call to org.openrdf.repository.base.AbstractRepositoryConnection is issued.  In stardog-sesame-core-4.1.3.jar this abstract class is missing! -> Workaround: search for an older stardog lib version of stardog-sesame-core (with some luck and optimism).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is: include openrdf-sesame-4.1.2-onejar.jar and the stardog code will compile.